# Initialization Vector (IV) -> toString('hex') -> write to file -> read from file-> hex to bin-> UndefinedUndefined Etc. NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, binary, hex

I am trying to store an Initialization Vector as a string hex, then retrieve it back to binary, but when I go to print the **result to the console, it says the following:**

```
fIV: undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined; Passphrase: passrig
```

Why is it printing undefined? And how can I achieve the desired result?
Assume that the IV is generated correctly...

**Relevant code:**

```
SignIn(pass)
{
    console.log(`fIV: ${h2b(fIV)}; Passphrase: ${pass}`);
    const key = crypto.scryptSync(pass, 'baethrowssalt', 32);
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, h2b(fIV)); 
    var decrypted = decipher.update(secret, 'hex', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');

    if(encrypted !== crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key).update(decrypted,'binary','hex') + cipher.final('hex'))
    {
        return alert(`access denied: encrypted:${encrypted}, secret:${secret}`);
    };
    return Buffer.from(decrypted, 'hex');

}

h2b(hex){
    return (parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2)).padStart(8, '0');
}
```

**Relevant snippet in the SignUp function**, I am writing to the IV file with:

```
   fs.writeFileSync(fileIV, iv.toString('hex'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example of writing an IV to file, then reading it back again. We're using hex encoding for the file data. It might well be easier to just write the IV in binary form to the file if you don't need to eyeball it, I've included examples of both.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");

// Write the IV to file in hex format and read it back again...
function testIVFileHex() {
    const IV = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    console.log("testIVFileHex: IV (write to file):  " + IV.toString("hex"));
    fs.writeFileSync("iv.txt", IV.toString("hex"));

    const IVFromFile = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync("iv.txt", "utf-8"), "hex");
    console.log("testIVFileHex: IV (read from file): " + IVFromFile.toString("hex"));
}

// Write the IV to file in binary format and read it back again...
function testIVFileBinary() {
    const IV = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    console.log("testIVFileBinary: IV (write to file):  " + IV.toString("hex"));
    fs.writeFileSync("iv.dat", IV);

    const IVFromFile = fs.readFileSync("iv.dat");
    console.log("testIVFileBinary: IV (read from file): " + IVFromFile.toString("hex"));
}

// On could use either function
testIVFileHex()
testIVFileBinary()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help man, this is clear.

Comment: it still doesnt allow me to use it in the decipher.update though. It gives me the following error still: Error: ```Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data```. I passed ```const fIV = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(fileIV, 'utf-8'), 'hex');``` that into ```var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, fIV);``` and used it here ```var decrypted = decipher.update(secret, 'hex', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');```

Comment: Are you using AES-GCM mode encrypted data? Is it possible you're missing the auth tag?